# Connect to a remote server mongoDB in Docker via ssh in nodeJS using tunnel-ssh, AuthenticationFailed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a remote server MongoDB in Docker through ssh in Nodejs as below :

```js
sshConfig = {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'host',
  port: 22,
  dstHost: '172.17.0.3',
  dstPort: 27017,
  localPort: 5000
};

const uri = 'mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/admin';

tunnel(sshConfig, async error => {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(`SSH connection error: ${error}`);
    }

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    async function run() {
      try {
        // Connect the client to the server
        await client.connect();
        // Establish and verify connection
        await client.db('admin').command({ ping: 1 });
        console.log('Connected successfully to server');
      } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        await client.close();
      }
    }
    await run().catch(console.dir);
  });
```

But I am getting error as below :

MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
at MessageStream.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:740:20)
at MessageStream.emit (node:events:390:28)
at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at processIncomingData (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:167:12)
at MessageStream._write (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:64:5)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28) {
ok: 0,
code: 18,
codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
},

and I open http://localhost:5000/ by browser, it shows that:

It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

I can connect the database via:

> 1. Use MongoDB compass to connect the database via ssh
> 2. Use `mongo 'mongodb://admin:password@remote-host:27017/admin'` in local machine terminal
> 3. Use `MongoClient(mongodb://admin:password@remote-host:27017/admin)` in Nodejs without ssh-tunnel
> 4. Use `mongo 'mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/admin'` in both remote host and remote host docker contaniner

I am sure the password is correct.

Comment: Did you create the admin user in the `admin` database? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I can use MongoDB compass to connect the database via ssh, I am sure the password is correct.